# Date Format shows wrong date

Tags: go

I'm trying to format a date like this: [daynumber] [monthname] [fullyear]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.Format("1 January 2014"))
}
```

However this prints out "11 November 10110" instead of the correct date "29 November 2014".

What is the correct way to use `Time.Format`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
fmt.Println(t.Format("2 January 2006"))
```

From [`Time.Format()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format)

> Format returns a textual representation of the time value formatted according to layout, which defines the format by showing how the reference time,

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

The article "[Parsing and formatting date/time in Go](http://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2011/05/go_time.html) " adds:

> The use of a mnemonic over obscure formatting codes I think reflects the pragmatism of Go’s developers and their focus on creating a language that makes its users more productive

Ironically, I have trouble remembering the exact values and order of that format template.
(Especially the day and month that I keep mixing up, being used to the dd-mm convention, as opposed to mm-dd).

Comment: Note: plat.golang.org does fake time: [http://blog.golang.org/playground#TOC_3.1.](http://blog.golang.org/playground#TOC_3.1.) 2009 is the expected year for `time.Now()`

Comment: Oh! So formatting only works if I use the values they set! I can rearrange "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006" how ever I want.

Comment: @425nesp yes, that is the idea of a "format template".